# ImportError: No module named gspread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gspread, oauth2client

I'm trying to work with the `gspread` library in python. i installed the lib with `pip install gspread` but when I run the code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://sreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('FILE_NAME.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open('Changelog').sheet1
print(wks.get_all_records())
```

it gives me an error:

```
File "stuff.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gspread
ImportError: No module named gspread
```

When I run it in python3 it gives me no import error. But those:

```
File "stuff.py", line 8, in <module>
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/__init__.py", line 38, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 51, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 819, in _do_refresh_request
    raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: https://sreadsheets.google.com/feeds is not a valid audience string.
```

Comment: after you installed it with pip, did you start a new python session? or is it a terminal window from before you installed gpsread? if so, you'll need a new one

Comment: which python version are you using? what OS?

Comment: Do you have both versions of Python installed on the same machine?  If so then there is probably a pathing issue.  Ideally you only want 1 install on your box.

Comment: @TheOne I use macOS, python 3.6.5

Comment: @NielsDingsbums did you try installing using pip3 instead of pip?

Answer (score 8):

It is possible that `pip install gspread` installed `gspread` to a different python interpreter.

Try the following to reinstall `gspread` in the python interpreter you want to use.

```
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gspread'])
```

---

EDIT: The method listed below has been [deprecated](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) and only works on Python 2.

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "gspread"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment! However, this is my code:

import sys, subprocess
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gspread'])
import gspread


And this is the ouput:
Requirement already satisfied: gspread in ...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'

Isn't this super weird?

Comment: That is weird. That message would seem to indicate pip knows about a package that is installed named "gspread", but no module named "gspread". The same way the Python package "Pillow" has as a module name of "PIL".

You may want to try adding the `--force-reinstall` flag to force pip to install gspread regardlessly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What fixed it for me was switching to a new virtual environment, this error stopped showing up. However, I am still very curious about the error that I got, that confirmed gspread was downloaded but it couldn't find it ahah

Answer (score 4):

if you're using `python3` you might need to use `pip3`.  Best practice would be to do it in a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv --python=3.6 myvenv
source myvenv
pip install gspread
python -m stuff.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python3, you should install the modules/libraries with pip3. And interpret the codes with 'python3' and not with 'python'. Then it will work for import instructions.

Comment: If you attempt to answer and twice the correct answer has been giving... why adding this blabla over python3 without giving straightforward solution? Keep in mind: coders are lazy but able to one-click the down-vote button in merely 500milliseconds. Please update to increase quality of answer. Welcome to SO ;-) End of Review (EoR).

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/gspread/#files

Download the tar file : gspread-3.6.0.tar.gz from the above link

```
$ tar -xf gspread-3.6.0.tar.gz
$ cd gspread-3.6.0
$ python3.6 setup.py install
Python 3.6.12 (default, Aug 18 2020, 02:08:22) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gspread
>>>
```

No error ...